# Asynchronous jquery - ajax when().then();

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to read the documents, but I'm having a hard time understanding some concepts:

```
$.when(function(){
    $.ajax({url:'php/Mostrarphp.php', type:'post',data: {queHacer:"MostrarUsuarios"}})
    .then(function(success) {

        $("#main").html(success);

    },function(error) {

        $("#main").html(error);

    });
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("test");
});
```

What I'm trying to do is for the first function to go into the PHP file and inside that file there is only an include to another file. After that I want to have a console log shown. (This is just practice for, when I need to run functions that retrieve data and will take longer).

The issue here is that the echo is not showing on the application, only shows what is resolved on the then (`console.log("test")`).

What is the correct way to have this execute the inside function and then the second one?

Comment: show the php code. the echo should pass data back to javascript

Comment: If you only do 1 ajax call / have 1 promise to resolve, there is not much use for the outer `.when` / `.then`. You can remove that and do everything in the inner success function.

Comment: <?php

$parametroid = $_POST["queHacer"];

 switch($parametroid){

  case "MostrarUsuarios":

    include("../bloques/grillausuarios.php");
    break;

 }

?>

Comment: jeroen as i was saying this is just template, the real function will go to a DB search data and fill the form, if i dont do this some times the information will be ready before the form to be filled.

Comment: No it won't. In your inner `.then` handler the ajax call has finished. By definition.

Comment: What  i want is for the inside function to show the result before executing the outside one. Using that code the inside function does not show anything.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you use `$.when`, you are creating a new promise, one that needs to be resolved.  Normally, `$.when` is used to "combine" multiple promises into one and then run a function once *all* of them resolve.

What you've passed to `$.when` is just a function.  A function that never gets run.  From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

> If a single argument is passed to `jQuery.when()` and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.

So, that means your `console.log("test");` is ran, but your AJAX code is never ran.

You do not not to use `$.when` here.  `$.ajax` *already* returns a promise, there's no need to make another one.  You can just *chain* `.then()` calls.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'php/Mostrarphp.php',
    type:'post',
    data: {queHacer:"MostrarUsuarios"}
}).then(function(success){
    $("#main").html(success);
},function(error){
    $("#main").html(error);
}).then(function(){
    console.log("test");
});
```

EDIT: In the comments you said:

> [no] matter how much time the inside execution takes to complete, the outside [should] always execute second

If this is what you want, then you *will* need to create another promise.  You can do that and then have it resolve once your "inside" function is complete.  I'd suggest wrapping your AJAX code in a function and having it return a promise that you can attach a callback to.

```
function ajaxCall(){
    var d = new $.Deferred;

    $.ajax({
        url:'php/Mostrarphp.php',
        type:'post',
        data: {queHacer:"MostrarUsuarios"}
    }).then(function(success){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#main").html(success);
            d.resolve();
        }, 2000);
    },function(error){
        $("#main").html(error);
        d.reject();
    });

    return d.promise();
}

ajaxCall().then(function(){
    console.log("test");
});
```

Comment: I tried this but when i put a setTiemout inside the first then it executes the sencond then before the first one:

$.ajax({
    url:'php/Mostrarphp.php',
    type:'post',
    data: {queHacer:"MostrarUsuarios"}
}).then(function(success){
    setTimeout(function(){console.log("inside")},2000);
},function(error){
    $("#main").html(error);
}).then(function(){
    console.log("test");
});

Comment: @MauroSebastianAquino: Yes, that's the correct behaviour.  What did you expect from a `setTiemout`?

Comment: I wanted to test that it does  not matter how much time the inside execution takes to complete, the outside will always execute second.

Comment: @MauroSebastianAquino: Is that what you *really* want here?  That's not what you described in your question.  If that's the case, then you *will* need to use another promise here.  You'll need to make a new promise and resolve it once your inside function is done.  Let me hack something up quickly.

Comment: @MauroSebastianAquino: I updated the answer.  Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, i am looking for a way that the outside code does not execute until the inside code is complete, and the inside code to be executed.

Comment: @MauroSebastianAquino: Does the 2nd block of code work for you?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: ajaxCall.then is not a function

Comment: @MauroSebastianAquino: Whoops, typo!  It should be `ajaxCall().then()`.  I updated the code in the answer.

Comment: Now i made it work but i'm back to the original problem, it only shows the message fron the outside and do not execute the code no the AjaxCall function.

Comment: @MauroSebastianAquino: What do you mean by "original problem"?  The code I show should work as-is.  Don't try to add in a `$.when` or anything.